# CHange URL after a modal is closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change my URL after a modal is clicked.

I had added an extra onClick to the button which called the modal, this was to a function - in that function I added some console logging.  I could see the logging, but the URL didn't change.

The (original) button code is:

```
<button className='buttonCheck' onClick={checkAnswer}>CHECK MY ANSWER</button> <CheckAnswerModal showModal={showCongratsModal} onClose={() => setShowCongratsModal(false)} videoMessage={showCongratsURL} content={showWindowContent} size='med'/>
```

And the modal

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

function CheckAnswerModal({showModal = false, onClose = () =>{}, videoMessage, content, size}) {

  return (
    <Modal
      size={size}
      show={showModal} 
      onHide={onClose}
      backdrop="static"
      keyboard={false}
    >

    <Modal.Body>
      {videoMessage ? <video src={videoMessage} controls autoPlay> </video>: <div><center>{content}</center></div>}
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
        Close
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
  )
}

export default CheckAnswerModal
```

Originally, I had added a new function to the calling page:

```
function GoHome() {
  console.log("redirecting")
  <Redirect to='/' />
}
```

and added this to the button onClick, I could see the logging, but no URL changing.  I've done a bit of looking about and I am pretty sure this is not working as the modal is on screen.  To get around this, in the GoHome() I even added a conditional (if the showModal is false, then do the logging)

I've seen some posts which talked about unmounting the component (now - this is something new to me, especially as I don't call any mount component explicitly.)

Am I missing something fundamental with redirect? Or can someone point me at what I am doing wrong (the redirect feels a little "hacky" just now, I need to redo a whole component I think, but this would work **for now**)

Comment: What kind of router are you using? `react-router`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `react-router-dom` if you have not installed yet.

Then import it.

`import {useNavigate} from react-router-dom`

then call it inside a function like:

`const navigate = useNavigate()`

then in your `onClose()` function use `navigate` like:

```
navigate("/")
```

- sorry for my English

Comment: Apologies I had installed react router v5 installed. 

Is navigate not the V6 way?

Comment: Then you can use `useHistory()`

Comment: `const history = useHistory()` `history('/')`

Comment: Hi Muhsin, that doesn't work - I get an error " Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. "

(to explain further, I put your code in a function called GoHome() and called that onClose of the button click

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to be smart, I simply declared history at the start and then in my onClose added history.push and it worked.